# Python SocketModule: 'str' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, sockets, attributeerror

I'm probably being really dumb but I can't resolve this error in a basic client script.

```
import socket

ipaddr = ""
desipaddr = ""
desport = 9999
myclient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def startclient(desipaddr):
    desipadd = raw_input("[+] Enter chatserver IP: ")
    desipaddr = str(desipadd)
    return desipaddr

def otherclient(desipaddr, myclient, desport):
    myclient.connect(desipaddr, desport)
    datatosend = raw_input("[+]>>> ")
    myclient.send(datatosend)
    datatoberecv = myclient.recv(1024)
    formatteddata = "[+] " + str(datatoberecv)
    print formatteddata


def main():
    startclient(desipaddr)
    otherclient(myclient, desipaddr, desport)

main()
```

"Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'connect'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined

```
def otherclient(desipaddr, myclient, desport):
```

But passed

```
otherclient(myclient, desipaddr, desport)
```

Comment: Oh thankyou, I didn't know that you need to pass arguments in the order they are defined :D

Comment: So how would you call a function if the names of the parameters are different in the function signature and the caller?

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments to `otherclient(myclient, desipaddr, desport)` reversed according to the function definition.